# I want to prove that knowing $P(A \mid C) > P(B \mid C)$ and $P(A \mid C^c) > P(B \mid C^c)$ then $P(A) > P(B)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I feel like I know this is true, but every time I try to break down the formulas with Baye's formulas and such I keep hitting a dead end. Is there any way someone can give me a hint on where to start, or maybe this is wrong and there is some counter example I should give.

Once again the idea is to prove that knowing $P(A \mid C) > P(B \mid C)$ and $P(A \mid C^c) > P(B \mid C^c)$ then $P(A) > P(B)$.

Comment: Why are you using Bayes' (named for Thomas Bayes, so note the position of the apostrophe is after the 's') formula instead of just $P(A \mid C) = P(A \cap C) / P(C)$?

Comment: Hint: $\Pr(A) = \Pr(A|C) \Pr(C) + \Pr(A|C^c) \Pr(C^c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the first relation implies that $\textbf{P}(A\cap C) > \textbf{P}(B\cap C)$.

Similarly, the second restriction implies that $\textbf{P}(A\cap C^{c}) > \textbf{P}(B\cap C^{c})$.

Based on the such assumptions, one has that:

\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A\cap C^{c}) - \textbf{P}(B\cap C^{c}) = \textbf{P}(A) - \textbf{P}(A\cap C) - \textbf{P}(B) + \textbf{P}(B\cap C) > 0
\end{align*}
where the last result tells us that:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(A) - \textbf{P}(B) > \textbf{P}(A\cap C) - \textbf{P}(B\cap C) > 0
\end{align*}
which is exactly the property we are looking for.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I would have thought knowing $\mathbb{P}(A\cap C) > \mathbb{P}(B\cap C)$ and $\mathbb{P}(A\cap C^c) > \mathbb{P}(B\cap C^c)$ leads to  $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap C)+\mathbb{P}(A\cap C^c)  > \mathbb{P}(B\cap C)+\mathbb{P}(B\cap C^c)= \mathbb{P}(B)$  by addition

Comment: @Henry Indeed, it is the proper way to approach it. Since my solution is (slightly) different from yours, I will keep it for the sake of comparison.

Answer (score -1):

We know:
\begin{align*}
P(A \mid C) & > P(B \mid C) \\
P(A \mid C^{\mathsf{c}}) & > P(B \mid C^{\mathsf{c}}) \\
P(C) & > 0 \\
P(C^{\mathsf{c}}) & > 0 \\
P(A) & = P(A \mid C) P(C) + P(A \mid C^{\mathsf{c}}) P(C^{\mathsf{c}}) \\
P(B) & = P(B \mid C) P(C) + P(B \mid C^{\mathsf{c}}) P(C^{\mathsf{c}})
\end{align*}
Note that $P(C) > 0$ is an implicit hypothesis, otherwise $P(A \mid C)$ is not defined. Likewise $P(C^{\mathsf{c}}) > 0$ is an implicit hypothesis, otherwise $P(A \mid C^{\mathsf{c}})$ is not defined.

From all these, it follows:
\begin{align*}
P(A \mid C) P(C) + P(A \mid C^{\mathsf{c}}) P(C^{\mathsf{c}}) & > P(B \mid C) P(C) + P(B \mid C^{\mathsf{c}}) P(C^{\mathsf{c}}) \\
P(A) & > P(B)
\end{align*}